# Discord.py Check if user registered their account

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I check if user is registered or not? Sometimes, people join without registering an account, so I want to create a command to check whether or not a user registered their account.

Comment: If I am right you can set that setting in your server settings, overview

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to chat on Discord without registering.

Comment: It's possible. You can try

Comment: No, it isn't. From a Discord Moderator, `Hi there! At the moment, Discord cannot be used without an account.`